How to hide a div class in woocommerce?
I have a woocommerce site and I'm trying to hide some elements after having identify the code with chrome developer tools
I have these elements, a pin and a green dot on each product image and I'd like to remove them
I discovered that they are two div class, but I don't know how I can hide these div classes
The code of one is the following:
<div class="featured-tag">
<div><i class="dticon-thumb-tack"></i><span>Featured</span></div></div>

The other one is:
<div class="product-custom-type"><span class="product-custom-type-label veg">Veg</span></div>

What code should I add in the css to hide these classes?

.featured-tag,
.product-custom-type {
    display: none;
}

Please take a CSS primer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Getting_started.

Thanks, using this works fine on chrome mobile and on desktop browsers, but It doesn't work on safari on ios where the hidden elements appear. Do you also know how to hide those elements on safari?

You'll need to inspect the applied CSS at mobile breakpoint, and adjust to override any existing styles that may be overriding the above code.

How can I inspect the code at mobile breakpoint?

Please take a CSS primer.

display: none;
You are talking about this?

Yes, I read about this, but how should I format the code to hide specifically those classes?

@marko988, CSS has been already written, so I will for controlling using JS: in CSS‘’’ .hidden {
display: none;
}                      “‘ “ JS: document.getElementById('myElement').classList.add('hidden');”       “ document.getElementById('myElement').classList.remove('hidden');”  And one more: only in JS: document.getElementById(….').style.display = 'block' or ‘none’;. Good luck!

More correctly: }                      “‘ “ JS: document.getElementById('….').classList.add('hidden');”       “ document.getElementById('….').classList.remove('hidden');”  And one more: only in JS: document.getElementById('...').style.display = 'block' or ‘none’;. Good luck!
